# Shrinking/Scaling iframe down to fit screen size

Tags: css, iframe

I have done a lot of research regarding this subject and have not been able to find an solution. So I am unsure if what I am trying to do is possible.

What I am trying to achieve:

I am wondering if it is possible to **scale** the iframe to 100% of the screen width, whilst preserving the aspect ratio. **NOTE: by scale, I am not speaking of, width:100%. I am talking about what the transform scale function does.**

I want to drag an element around inside that iframe at 1920x1080px, but even if the screen resolution was 500px, they would still be viewing a "zoomed out" version of the iframe that is 100% width of their screen. Once I then get the position of that dragged element inside my iframe, I want it to be relative to 1920px and not the "zoomed" out version, is it possible for these to be seperate?

Not sure if this is possible though and I find it quite difficult to explain. So I made an image to demonstrate.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pux5I.png

I have tried both the img method for keeping the ratio and the padding-top method. *These methods at first seem to do the trick, but they are not "zooming", "shrinking" the element, they are just resizing it. I want to scale the element so that it fits 100% width.*

It only needs to work in modern browsers.

Is there any sort of css/javascript solution?

Comment: For those suggesting that this is a duplicate, it is not. Please read the full question in context and understand the unique problem.

Comment: yes I read. it's not quite a dup. you want to preserve the aspect ratio. well, you would need js calculations on the resize event so the width will be 100% and the height will be preserve it's ratio. what's the problem? I didn't understand how would you scale an element...this is close to impossible

Comment: @vsync, the point is it's not supposed to just be a "resize", I'm speaking of scaling it down. For example, when you use `transform: scale(.7)`, it scales the element. I was wondering if it was possible to "scale" the iframe according to 100% width.

Comment: no it's not possible to know what value to apply to the transform..it would require an interval in which you put some value, check if it's close to 100%, if not, adjust, until it's perfect, and then clear the interval.

Comment: @vsync You're probably right. I think the best solution would probably be to use media queries for each screen resolution and scale manually for each one.